# Cogrouping not supported in streaming DataSet/DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

> Executing action:Metrics:P{"input":"tripMetrics","isEnabled":"true","class":"com.mobileum.wcmodel.execution.actions.SaveStreamAction","properties":{"path":"output/tripMetrics","triggerWindow":"5 minutes","checkpointLocation":"output/checkpoints/tripMetrics","format":"console","queryName":"GtpDetailModel"}}}
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: CoGrouping with a streaming DataFrame/Dataset is not supported;;

I have a use case where I have to cogroup two datasets in streaming . However when doing so I am getting an exception that Cogrouping of Dataset/DataFrames in streaming is not supported

```
 @Override
    public List<Dataset<Row>> transform(SparkSession sparkSession, Map<String, Dataset<Row>> inputDatasets, Properties properties) {

    Encoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply((StructType)new CatalystSqlParser(sparkSession.sqlContext().conf()).parseDataType("struct<hostnetworkid:string,partnercountryid:string>"));

    try {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Dataset<Row>>> itr= inputDatasets.entrySet().iterator();
         Dataset<Row> trip = null;
         Dataset<Row> registration= null;
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            trip=itr.next().getValue();
            registration=itr.next().getValue();

        }

        KeyValueGroupedDataset<Long, TripModel> tripKeyValueGroupedDataset =
                trip.map((MapFunction<Row, TripModel>) TripModel :: new , Encoders.bean(TripModel.class))
                        .groupByKey((MapFunction<TripModel, Long>) TripModel::getKey, Encoders.LONG());

        KeyValueGroupedDataset<Long, RegistrationModel> regKeyValueGroupedDataset =
                registration.map((MapFunction<Row, RegistrationModel>) RegistrationModel :: new , Encoders.bean(RegistrationModel.class))
                        .groupByKey((MapFunction<RegistrationModel, Long>) RegistrationModel::getKey, Encoders.LONG());

        Dataset<Row> cogrouped = tripKeyValueGroupedDataset.cogroup(regKeyValueGroupedDataset, (CoGroupFunction<Long,TripModel, RegistrationModel, Row>) ( key,  it1,  it2) ->
        {

            Iterable<TripModel> iterable = () -> it1;
            List<TripModel> tripModelList = StreamSupport
                    .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
         List<Row> a1 = new ArrayList<Row>();
            a1.add(RowFactory.create(tripModelList.get(0).getCosid(),"asdf"));
            return a1.iterator();
```

Comment: Yes, as the error message says: using cogroup with two streaming dataframes are nto supported. What is your question here?